# Is the order of entries in class __annotations__ consistent with their definition?

Tags: python, annotations

Suppose we have a class definition:

```
class A:
    z: 1
    b: 2
    Z: 3
    g: 4
    C: 5
    A: 6
    d: 7
```

The standard CPython gives this value for `A.__annotations__`:

```
{
    'z': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'Z': 3,
    'g': 4,
    'C': 5,
    'A': 6,
    'd': 7
}
```

Is that always the case? What does the specification say about this?

Comment: Dictionaries retain insertion order from CPython 3.6, and it's required in all implementations from 3.7. The attributes themselves certainly are, I'd expect the annotations to be too.

Answer (score 4):

The specification for the Syntax of Variable Annotations given in [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) states the following:

> at the module or class level, if the item being annotated is a simple
> name, then it and the annotation will be stored in the `__annotations__`
> attribute of that module or class (mangled if private) as an ordered
> mapping from names to evaluated annotations.

So an ordered mapping seems to be guaranteed *by default*. However, the PEP also states the following:

> `__annotations__` is writable ... But attempting to update
> `__annotations__` to something other than an ordered mapping may
> result in a TypeError ... (Note that the assignment to `__annotations__`
> ... is accepted by the Python interpreter without questioning it - but
> the subsequent type annotation expects it to be a MutableMapping ...)

So, since a `MutableMapping` isn't inherently ordered, it is at least possible that the `__annotations__` of a third-party class could be a mapping that defines an arbitrary order:

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

class D(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._d = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._d[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._d[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._d[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return reversed(self._d)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._d)


class A:
    __annotations__ = D()
    z: 1
    b: 2
    Z: 3
    g: 4
    C: 5
    A: 6
    d: 7

for item in A.__annotations__.items():
    print(item)
```

```
('d', 7)
('A', 6)
('C', 5)
('g', 4)
('Z', 3)
('b', 2)
('z', 1)
```